# Can't make Tensorflow run on GPU

Tags: python, cuda, tensorflow

hello ubuntu community,

I am trying to train a new model of deepspeech, like in this [description](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/TRAINING.html).
If I follow every single step, I can train a model. But it is training on my CPU.
I tried to install on my ubuntu 18.04.05 system the [cuda-10.2](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.2-download-archive) and/or [cuda-10.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive) with the runfile. I added the **$PATH** and the **$LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to the **.bashsrc**. Of course I installed the latest related cudnn lib. I tried it with the **dpkg -i** command and also by [unziping the archive and coping](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) the files to the related cuda folder:

```
sudo cp ...-archive/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp -P ...-archive/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

But still, it is not running on my GPU. If use Anaconda, so I create an environment like this:

> `conda create -n my-env python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu=1.15.0`

It works in the sense that the GPU is used. Unfortunately it runs in to an error later. I assume this error has to do with some lib version problems.
But anyways, I would like to know what the problem without conda is. I know that conda comes with an independent version of cuda/cudnn and is doing the linking by itself. But what is going wrong with my linking. Is there any obvious mistake or a step missing? I could manage it in the past for cuda 11.x, but it is already a couple of month ago and it wasn't that hard the last time.
I am happy for any hint.

BR Michael

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue in the past, and with some digging, it is mainly due to the fact that Conda tends to use it's own version of CUDA and CUDNN that is sperate to the system (as it allows for less problems).

I would personally highly recommend using `mamba`(https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba), as I have had much better speeds, seems much more reliable, and all the commands are just drop in replacements. For this, just install the 'CUDN', and CUDA is a dependancy of it via something like (using `conda` for this, but feel free to replace `conda` with `mamba` if you prefer):

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudnn cudatoolkit
```

Something like the below should get you up and running on bare metal if you prefer that (assuming that you are using Ubuntu):

```sh
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
whereis cuda
```

Download the CUDNN binary from Nvidia (https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/form/cudnn-download-survey)

Extract using `tar -xvzf path-to-binary`

Then copy it over into the CUDA installation folder (make sure to correspond it with the output of `whereis cuda`), although I'll give an example here:

```sh
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/lib/cuda/include/
sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/cuda/lib64/
```

Change to the correct user permissions next (all + read):

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/lib/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

You can then add everything to the `$PATH` variable via something like:

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/include:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then to reload your shell just do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then install TensorFlow using `pip`:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

For both installations, try something like the below to make sure that you are able to use your GPU.

Enter the Python shell (something like `python3` in your terminal)

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

If everything went alright, should have something similar to the above, and you may have more if you have more than 1 GPU.

Hope that helps!